# Trying to call ThenInclude on return-value of custom method

Tags: c#, .net-core, architecture, entity-framework-core

I'm working in .net core 3.0 and Entity Framework Core 5 using Jetbrains Rider.

I'm developping an application, and I'm currently trying to create methods to make eager loading possible and easy to do from the business-logic layer without directly accessing our DbContext object (which is only accessible as private readonly field of repository classes).

To give you an idea of what I'm trying to do, this is what I've already made (irrelevent to my question, just for context). This method is defined in a static class in my technical services layer, which I can call without accessing my DbContext object directly (I only specify which navigational property I want to load from database as a parameter)

```cs
public void ReferenceNavProperty<T>(T obj, Expression<Func<T, object>> expression, bool loadAll)
    where T : class
{
    var reference = context.Entry(obj).Reference(expression);
    if (reference != null)
        context.Entry(obj).References.Append(reference);

    if (loadAll)
        LoadAllReferenced(obj); //<- does a .Load() on every EntryReference and CollectionEntry of the specified object
}
```

So whenever I retrieve an object that has a navigational property which I want to load, I call this method like this:

```cs
ReferenceNavProperty<Session>(session, s => s.SomeNavigationalProperty, true);
```

And I have succesfully loaded a navigational property by only specifying *which* property, and thus respecting the architecture.

**Now for the question:**
I want to accomplish something similar, for eager loading.
The previous example on explicit loading was fairly simple, because I can easily split EntryReference/EntryCollections from the .Load() method and then later on Load all those references.
With eager loading, however, methods Include() and ThenInclude() need to be chained to one another, I tried to also split those 2 (so I don't have to chain them necesarily), this is what I tried at first:

```cs
// T is a generic class type variable
public IIncludableQueryable<T, object> ReadAndInclude(Expression<Func<T, object>> expression)
{
    //context is a private readonly field of type DbContext
    return context.Set<T>().Include(expression);
}
```

This method would access the DbContext and Include the first property (expression), but then it would return an IIncludableQueryable interface so that the caller (that's calling this method) can chain multiple Include() or ThenInclude() calls on this this IIncludableQueryable interface, and thus making eager loading accessible from the business-logic layer without directly accessing our DbContext object.

This actually works. Kind of...
If I do the following:

```cs
//SessieDeelnames and Klas are just 2 navigational properties of session
sessieRepo.ReadAndInclude(session => session.SessieDeelnames).Include(session => session.Klas);
```

When I call .Include() (to include that second child for property 'Klas') then it works.
but when I try it with .ThenInclude (because ReadAndInclude already includes a property, I should be able to chain a call to ThenInclude), it doesn't recognize the source's property:

```cs
sessieRepo.ReadAndInclude(session => session.SessieDeelnames).ThenInclude(/* ??? */);
```

[My intellisense doesn't recognize the type of the prviously chained property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrRjw.jpg)

If you'd ask me, I'd say this has to do with the fact that my method's return type is:

```cs
IIncludableQueryable<T, object> //<- object is the problem
```

This is what I think is wrong, but I have no clue of how to specify the actual class-type of the property. I'm not sure, but if I view the documentation for ThenInclude() I see they use reflection to find out what the property type is? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Suggestions, solutions or remarks on repsecting architecture are all welcome.

Comment: Why not expose `IQueryable<TEntity>` properties, as EF-based repositories were designed to?  And then the business logic layer can compose the queries directly instead of going through some convoluted intermediate API.

Comment: If you decide to parametrize Includes then do *all* of them. Maybe using something like [this](https://dotnetfalcon.com/converting-traditional-ef-includes-to-ef-core-includes/) (didn't try it).